# How do you get to Whirlpool level?

Tags: angry-birds-epic

I see a whirlpool on my map of Angry Birds Epic. But it's not clickable.

Yet, I see references to "whirlpool level" on various Wikis/Youtube videos.

How to I get to it? Or is it still too early for me? (I just got the submarine)

Comment: I didn't find out about it until I beat the game, but its clickable for me, so its unlocked at some point between where you are at and the end of the game :D

Comment: Simple you win.

Comment: @stizzle84 what do you mean by "win" precisely? Beating the last castle? Since it's unmarked I hadn't realized it's clickable so I don't know at which point it became available for me too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is definitely sometime after you get a submarine, and between conquering your 6th (Bottomless cave) and 7th (Sunken Pyramid) dungeon.

I think it was Sunken Pyramid dungeon. I never needed to do anything special to open it, aside from (likely) completing the Sunken Pyramid.